# Metro layout align bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'am working on a metro-ish layout for android, but i can seem to make it work the same on all devices. On a Galaxy Note3 it doesn't align to the bottom (too much gap between buttons), and on a smaller screen Galaxy Ace2 it fits too crowded (some buttons next to each other)

This is my layout, any ideas on how to make it universal would be great! Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_feed"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/feed"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Feed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_profile"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_new_challenge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_new_challenge"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/new_challenge"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="New Challenge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_rankings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_rankings"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rankings"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Rankings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_factory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_factory"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/task_factory"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Task Factory"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_settings"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gadgets"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_gadgets"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/gadgets"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Gadgets"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_store"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_store"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/store"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Store"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_help"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/help"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note3]

[image: Samsung Galaxy Ace2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have content that takes the whole space height you will have to play with the weight of your child `Views` and their respective height.

I don't get where is your first image `icon_photo`. Doesn't look to be in your screenshots.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_feed"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/feed"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Feed"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_profile"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_new_challenge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_new_challenge"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/new_challenge"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="New Challenge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_rankings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_rankings"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rankings"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Rankings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_factory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_factory"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/task_factory"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Task Factory"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_settings"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gadgets"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_gadgets"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/gadgets"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Gadgets"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_store"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_store"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/store"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Store"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_help"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/help"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dip"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

The difference between those screen is high. You will maybe have to play with different layouts or different box sizes using the `values` but if your `drawables` size are not the same you can probably deal without having multiple layouts.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I would create different layout folders for different resolution, density. I wouldn't just use one xml for all different phone sizes out there. You probably want to pick out the most popular ones and just aim for those.